# Analytic version of Hahn-Banach using geometric version

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing

When studying the Hahn-Banach theorem, one can demonstrate the geometric version from scratch and use it to prove the analytic version, as is outlined in [Hahn-Banach theorem: 2 versions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102588/hahn-banach-theorem-2-versions).

To do so, it is necessary to show that the cone $ C = \{(x,t)\,:\,p(x) \lt t\} \subset X $ is open. ¿How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topology you use on $C $ is the product topology, so basic open sets are products of an open set in $E $ and an open set in $\mathbb R $. We can write
$$
C=\bigcup_{t>0}\{x:\ p (x)<t\}\times (-\infty,t).
$$

Comment: And how do we know $ \{x:\ p (x)<t\} $ is open? p is supposed to be semilinear but I'm not sure if that implies continuity

Comment: Continuity with respect to what? The topology on $E$ is the one given by $p$, so it is generated by the sets $\{x:\ p(x-y)<r\}$.

Comment: I'm considering $E$ with a previously defined topology, given by a norm. Now I start to think that this proof doesn't apply to this situation

Comment: That's your choice. But then you are not following the proof in the answer you quoted. And what's your $p$, if it is not related to the topology?

Comment: In my version of the geometric version (from the book by Brezis) $p$ is the Minkowsky functional and the space is normed. I wanted a similar setting to go back. That's because I say that now I see there are different situations

Comment: In a normed space, the Minkowsky functional is the norm.

Comment: I meant the Minkowsky functional for a convex subset, as in the other proof. But I see your point